# How to resolve when the IP of a NFS server changes

Tags: ip, nfs, unmounting

I have a Windows NFS server and several CentOS linux servers which were mounting volumes from it.  The Windows server moved to a new network and even though DNS works and the NFS mount was mounted by hostname, it appears the NFS client also makes note of the ipaddr value, which is no longer valid.  This causes the typical hanging mounts, df, issues one would expect.  How do I resolve this retroactively?

Comment: Did you try restarting networking?

Answer (score 2):

If the IP address has changed then you'll likely need to restart the NFS clients and/or run the `umount` command explicitly releasing the mounted service. This may not be able to complete though, with the original NFS service is now gone.

The only other approach that I was able to find was this one, written up in this Linux Journal article titled: [How-To: Release Stuck NFS Mounts without a Reboot](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/how-release-stuck-nfs-mounts-without-reboot). I've never used this approach and until today never heard of this method but it does sound feasible in looking through it.

Also I believe you may run into issues depending on whether the NFS mount was mounted with intr/nointr. You can read more about this feature switch in the NFS man page, `man nfs`.

*excerpt*

```
intr / nointr  Selects whether to allow signals to interrupt file operations 
               on this mount point. If neither option is specified (or if 
               nointr is specified), signals do  not  interrupt NFS file 
               operations. If intr is specified, system calls return EINTR 
               if an in-progress NFS operation is interrupted by a signal.

               Using the intr option is preferred to using the soft option 
               because it is significantly less likely to result in data
               corruption.

               The  intr  / nointr mount option is deprecated after kernel 
               2.6.25.  Only SIGKILL can interrupt a pending NFS operation 
               on these kernels, and if specified, this mount option is 
               ignored to provide backwards compatibility with older
               kernels.
```

Comment: How do you restart the NFS client?  I know the server side, but don't think I ever needed to restart the client side.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - they aren't directly client, more services that help facilitate NFS. `/etc/init.d/nfslock` is one of them.

Comment: I used umount -l which allowed me to unmount the nfs volume.  This solves my problem.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - sorry I thought you had already tried umounting that, or I would've suggested that. I don't have the `-l` switch on any version I have of umount. What does the man page say it will do?

Comment: I tried regular umount , -l is lazy which means it will unmount it first, then resolve open file handles and whatnot later when/if possible.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - yeah it probably get's the reference to the mount out of the system, whether the mount actually goes away or not, doesn't really matter, given the mount at the other end is now gone/moved anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317/force-unmount-of-nfs-mounted-directory) has steps that have worked for me. In a nutshell:

- Assign Old IP of NFS server to an alias. `ifconfig eth0:fakenfs Old_IP netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
- `umount -l /mount`
- bring down the alias: `ifconfig eth0:fakenfs down`
- Mount the NFS share again: `mount -a`